# Connect Oracle business intiligence report (OBIE) to Power BI

Tags: oracle, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop, obiee

I am learning data visualization using Power BI. My organization uses OBIEE to retrieve the reports (Data tables). I want to make my dash bords live. I want to establish a connection between Power BI and OBIEE. IF use the data connection option from power bi it is giving error by saying necessary client is not installed.

Comment: Power BI and OBIEE are competing visualization tools. You shouldn't use one to provide data to the other.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably one of the worst possible combinations of misconceptions I have recently read.

OBI doesn't "retrieve the reports (Data tables)". OBI is an analytics platform with the capabilities of Power BI in terms of data visualization plus everything a solution like Denodo gives you (data virtualization) plus security plus etc etc.

Using Power BI on top of OBI is akin to looking at the Mona Lisa but display it as an 8bit graphics with monochrome colour scheme.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with me .

Answer (score 0):

I think you tried using [BI Connector](https://www.biconnector.com). If yes, you should [install the connector](https://support.biconnector.com/support/solutions/folders/8000085842) first, and set up your OBIEE DSNs. Then try [connecting to that DSN](https://support.biconnector.com/support/solutions/folders/8000085846) from Power BI Desktop using "BI Connector" under "Get Data".